# How to Create Multiple runners for different flutter versions?

Tags: flutter, gitlab, gitlab-ci, cicd

So there are two types of runners in Gitlab

1. Specific Runners
2. Shared Runners

I have used Specific Runner and created a runner instance with `SHELL` as my Executor. so my machine itself a runner now. In my Machine, flutter 3.10 is configured so it works well with the below script.

```
stages:
  - test # All jobs related for testing dsuch as Unit Test
  - build
  - deploy
#
flutter_test: # Name of the lane
  stage: test # type of stage
  script:
    - flutter test # Run Flutter tests
  tags:
    - flutter # Tags for runner
  only:
    - main

flutter_build_android_dev: #Job nameDd
  stage: build # kind of job
  before_script:
    - flutter packages get
    - flutter clean
  script:
    - flutter build apk --flavor=dev -t lib/application/main/main_dev.dart
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-dev-release.apk
    expire_in: 1 day
  tags:
    - flutter
  only:
    - main
#
deploy_android_dev: #deployd
  stage: deploy
  dependencies:
    - flutter_build_android_dev
  script:
    - appcenter login --token $APPCENTER_API_TOKEN
    - appcenter distribute release -f build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-dev-release.apk -g Collaborators --app balajiramadoss/passion
  tags:
    - flutter
  only:
    - main

##
## build ios dev33e3
##dd
flutter_build_ios_dev:
  stage: build
  before_script:
    - flutter packages get
    - flutter clean
  script:
    - flutter build ipa --flavor=dev -t lib/application/main/main_dev.dart --export-method=ad-hoc
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - build/ios/ipa/StarterDev.ipa
    expire_in: 1 day
  tags:
    - flutter
  only:
    - main

deploy_ios_dev:
  stage: deploy
  dependencies:
    - flutter_build_ios_dev
  script:
    - appcenter login --token $APPCENTER_API_TOKEN
    - appcenter distribute release -f build/ios/ipa/StarterDev.ipa -g Collaborators --app balajiramadoss/starter
  tags:
    - flutter
  only:
    - main
```

Now another project requires flutter 3.7 how do I create a runner for the specific flutter version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To support multiple Flutter versions with GitLab CI/CD, you would need to set up runners with different Flutter versions installed.
That means:

- installing the specific version of Flutter you need on the runner machine or use a version manager like [`fvm` (Flutter Version Management)](https://fvm.app/docs/advanced/custom_version) (install it with `dart pub global activate fvm`), from the [`leoafarias/fvm`](https://github.com/leoafarias/fvm) project.
- [registering a new runner](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/register/) on your GitLab instance for the project that requires the different Flutter version.
- [assigning tags](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#tags) to your runners to differentiate them, like `flutter-3.10` and `flutter-3.7`.
- specifying, in your `.gitlab-ci.yml`, the tag that corresponds to the runner with the version of Flutter you need.

For each project, install the required Flutter version:

```bash
fvm install 3.7 # for the project that needs Flutter 3.7
fvm install 3.10 # for the project that needs Flutter 3.10
```

In the `.gitlab-ci.yml` for the project that requires Flutter 3.7, use `fvm` to run Flutter commands:

```yaml
stages:
  - test
  - build
  - deploy

flutter_test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - fvm use 3.7
    - fvm flutter test
  tags:
    - flutter-3.7
  only:
    - main

# Rest of the .gitlab-ci.yml configuration
```

Do not forget to tag the runner when you register it using the `gitlab-runner register` command, and provide the `flutter-3.7` tag when prompted.

```
+----------------+               +----------------+           +----------------+
|                |  Specific     |                |  Shared   |                |
| GitLab Server  +-------------->+ Runner Machine +<----------+ Other Projects |
|                |  Runner       | (Flutter 3.10) |  Runner   | (Flutter 3.7)  |
+----------------+               +----------------+           +----------------+
```

For the updated `.gitlab-ci.yml`, you need to adjust the `tags` for each job to target the specific runner you want to use.
You may also want to use `fvm` in your scripts to make sure the right Flutter version is being used.
The `tags` in your script will target the specific runner by its tag.

Comment: This solution gives me ideas. Thanks a lot @VonC